# Maven omitting dependency

Tags: maven

Using Apache Maven 3.3.9. I have a project that pulls some spring dependencies transitively. This is what I get:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose|grep spring-c
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

All above are compile scope, so all should be included. However, for some reason, spring-core is being completely omitted.

Strange enough, this looks like a depth problem. As you can see above the main project has dependency A that has dependency B that includes spring-context. Set up this way, it does not pull spring-core.

However, if I also include dependency B in my project pom directly in `<dependency>` (i.e. instead of relying A to transitively include B), it pulls spring-core as expected:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose|grep spring-c
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
```

As you can see in row 4 of the maven output, spring-core is now included. That is, moving spring-context one level up seems to cause it's spring-core dependency to be pulled in.

Any idea why this is happening?